Using AWS Certificate Manager Certs(private) how to add certificate on nginx:alpine Docker image?
I'm trying to run a React-based application using the nginx:alpine Docker image with SSL enabled. I'm using AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) private certificates for my domain. I followed the steps to export the certificates from ACM, and I’ve created the necessary files, including the private key, certificate, certificate chain, and root CA.
Even though the website loads over HTTPS, the browser is still showing that it's "Not Secure." I'm not sure if the problem lies in how I'm setting up Nginx to use these certificates or in how the certificates are handled.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Exported my domain certificate, private key, and certificate chain from ACM using the aws acm export-certificate command.
Combined the certificates as needed and copied them into my Docker image.
Added the root CA certificate from ACM to the trusted CA list.
Configured Nginx to serve the site over HTTPS using these certificates.
Here’s the Dockerfile I'm using to set up my Nginx container:
# Use an official Nginx image to serve the React app
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the build folder contents into the Nginx server's root directory
COPY build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

# Copy AWS private certs - SSL certificate, private key, and chain to the container
COPY cert/certificate.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt
COPY cert/decrypted-key.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/private-key.pem
COPY cert/certificate-chain.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate-chain.crt

# Copy the AWS private CA root certificate into the image
COPY cert/root-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root-ca.crt
# Update CA certificates in the image
RUN update-ca-certificates

# Set the correct permissions for SSL certificates and private key
RUN chmod 600 /etc/nginx/ssl/private-key.pem \
    && chmod 644 /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt \
    && chmod 644 /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate-chain.crt \
    && chmod 600 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root-ca.crt

# Copy the custom nginx.conf to the correct location
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose both HTTP and HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]



Even though the website loads over HTTPS, the browser is still showing that it's "Not Secure."

That's because you are using a private certificate. Private certificates are not intended to be used with web browsers. Only public certificates will be accepted and authenticated by your web browser.
